# CORS with Spring not working

Tags: javascript, spring, mongodb, cross-domain, cors

I have this well-known issue with **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in my Spring application. I use cross-domain request to read data from built in **MongoDB** database REST interface (for example : http:\localhost:28017\db_name\collection_name ).

My javascript client (JSONP doesnt work :( ) is very similar to this one on this webpage : http://2rdscreenretargeting.blogspot.com/2012/06/enable-cors-for-jersey.html. I also use CORS Filter from this website : http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html.

Every response from my Spring app has in their header this Access-Control-Allow-Origin attribute, except response from mongodb. What else can i do ?

Comment: Can you verify that the MongoDB request has an Origin header? This is what triggers the CORS request.

Answer (score 0):

My request to MongoDB looks like this one :

**Accept:*/*
Origin:localhost:8080 
Referer:localhost:8080/SpringHighcharts/chartmongo 
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17**

I also found that **mongod** has parameter --json which **Permits JSONP access via an HTTP interface. Consider the security implications of allowing this activity before enabling this option**, but even enabling this option does not change anything i suppose ;/